# Can't find the mistake (StackOverflowError)

Tags: java, windows, swing, sudoku, stack-overflow

I'm writing a Sudoku-solving program, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.AppContext.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.flushPendingEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.postEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.changeCaretPosition(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.handleSetDot(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.setDot(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$Handler.insertUpdate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(Unknown Source)
```

I can't find the reason for this error. The code of my programm is as follows:

```
package code;

import java.awt.Color;                                         //Import nötiger Klassen
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 




public class SOLVE implements ActionListener{

private int[][] matrix;                         //Eingelesenes Sudokufeld
private boolean[][]input;                       //Überfrüfungsfeld zur bestimmung von eingegebenen Zahlen

private JFrame fenster;                         //GUI Fenster
private JTextArea field[][];                    //GUI Text Sudoku Feld
private JButton start;                          //Start Button
private JButton reset;


public void gui(){                                            //Erstellt die Grafische Oberfläche
    Border b1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.black );

    //Erstellt Fenster
    fenster = new JFrame();
    fenster.setLocation(100, 100);
    fenster.setSize(500, 320);
    fenster.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    fenster.setTitle("Sudoku Solver");

    //Erstellt Sudoku TextFelder
    field = new JTextArea[9][9];
    int x = 0;      //x-Koordinate
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        int y = 0;     //y-Koordinate
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            field[i][j] = new JTextArea();
            field[i][j].setLocation((200+x),(30+y));
            field[i][j].setSize(20, 20);
            field[i][j].setText("0");
            field[i][j].setBorder(b1);
            field[i][j].setVisible(true);
            fenster.add(field[i][j]);
            if(j==2||j==5){
                y=y+32;
            }
            else{
                y=y+25;
            }
        }
        if(i==2||i==5){
            x=x+32;
        }
        else{
            x=x+25;
        }
    }

    //Erstellt Start Button
    start = new JButton();
    start.setText("Solve");
    start.setSize(150,50);
    start.setLocation(30,30);
    start.addActionListener(this);

    //Erstellt Reset Button
    reset = new JButton();
    reset.setText("Reset");
    reset.setSize(150,50);
    reset.setLocation(30,100);
    reset.addActionListener(this);


    //Fügt Komponenten zum Fenster hinzu
    fenster.add(reset);
    fenster.add(start);
    fenster.setVisible(true);
}

public SOLVE(){                                               //Startet Klasse
    gui();
    matrix = new int[9][9];
    input = new boolean[9][9];
}

public void copy(){                                           //Einlesen der TextFelder in die Matrix une Überprüfungs Matrix
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(field[i][j].getText());
            if(matrix[i][j]!=0){
                input[i][j]=false;
            }
            else{
                input[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }   
}

public boolean check(int x,int y, int solution){              //Überprüfung ob Lösung möglich ist für eine bestimmte Zahl bei einem bestimmten Feld
    boolean moeglich = false; //Insgesammt möglich
    boolean wmoeglich = true; //Waagrecht möglich
    boolean smoeglich = true; //Senkrecht möglich
    boolean fmoeglich = true; //Feld möglich

    //Überprüft waagrecht und senkrecht ob möglich
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        if(matrix[x][i]==solution){
            wmoeglich = false;
        }
        if(matrix[i][y]==solution){
            smoeglich = false;
        }
    }
    //Sucht nötiges Feld und überprüft dieses

    //Oberste Reihe
    if(x<3){
        //linkes Feld
        if(y<3){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //mittleres Feld
        else if(y<6&& y>2){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(int j=3;j<6;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //rechtes Feld
        else if(y<9 && y>5){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(int j=6;j<9;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //mittlere Reihe
    else if(x<6 && x>2){
        //linkes Feld
        if(y<3){
            for(int i=3;i<6;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //mittleres Feld
        else if(y<6 && y>2){
            for(int i=3;i<6;i++){
                for(int j=3;j<6;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //rechtes Feld
        else if(y<9 && y>5){
            for(int i=3;i<6;i++){
                for(int j=6;j<9;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //unterste Reihe
    else if(x<9 && x>5){
        //linkes Feld
        if(y<3){
            for(int i=6;i<9;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //mittleres Feld
        else if(y<6 && y>2){
            for(int i=6;i<9;i++){
                for(int j=3;j<6;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //rechtes Feld
        else if(y<9 && y>5){
            for(int i=6;i<9;i++){
                for(int j=6;j<9;j++){
                    if(matrix[i][j]==solution){
                        fmoeglich = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //wenn eine Überprüfung fehlgeschlagen Lösung nicht möglich
    if(smoeglich == true && wmoeglich == true && fmoeglich == true){
        moeglich = true;
    }
    return moeglich;
}

public void search(int i, int j){                             //Lösen des Sudokus (Eigentlich Rekursiv)
    if(input[i][j]==true){  //Wenn keine menschliche eingabe
        int l = 1;
        for(l=1;l<10;l++){
            if(check(i,j,l)==true){  //Wenn Überprüfung erfolgreich war
                  matrix[i][j]=l;    //Schreibt Lösung in Matrix
                  field[i][j].setText(""+l); //Und Schreibt Lösung in TextFeld

                  //Nachfolger suchen
                    if(i<=7){
                       search(i+1,j);   
                    }
                    else if(i==8 && j<=7){
                        search(i-8,j+1);
                    }
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
            }
            //Da Rekursion nicht funktionierte hier den Schritt zurück 
            else if(check(i,j,l)==false && l==9){
                matrix[i][j]=0;
                if(i>0){
                    search(i-1,j);
                }
                else if(i==0 && j>0){
                    search(i+8,j-1);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //Nachfolger suchen
        if(i<=7){
             search(i+1,j);      
        }
        else if(i==8 && j<=7){
            search(i-8,j+1);
        }
        else{}
    }
}

public void reset(){                                          //Resettet Fenster und Matrix
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            field[i][j].setText("0");
            matrix[i][j]=0;
            input[i][j]=true;
        }
    }
}

public void master(){                                         //Master Methode (Führt die nötigen Methoden nacheinander aus)
    System.gc();
    copy();
    search(0,0);    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {                      //Main Methode (Start Methode)
    new SOLVE();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){                 //Button Abfrage
    Object source = evt.getSource();

    if(source==start){  //Wenn Button 'start' keklckt wird Methode main ausführen
        master();
    }
    else if(source == reset){
        reset();
    }
}
}
```

What could be the cause of this error? Sorry about the comments in the code being in German, but if you want I could translate them into English.

Comment: You haven't posted enough stacktrace to diagnose the problem. With StackOveflowErrors you must find a complete cycle in the trace.

Comment: It looks like `search()` recursively calls itself. My guess is that it goes too deep calling itself and exhausts the stack memory.

Comment: @stvcisco No, that's definetely not it. Look at the stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the stacktrace isn't complete, how do you know it's definitely not due to recursion?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the stacktrace would indeed have to show a lot of calls to search, and it might very well do that before finally running out of stack during the setText call which occurs within the search method.  We'll know more when OP shows the full stack trace. Right now there isn't enough data.

Comment: @stvcisco Indeed you are right, that is a plausible scenario, even though many branches which involve recursion do not involve that call.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I got curious and tried it myself. I did get a StackOverflowError and the stack was full of repeated calls to `search(i,j)`. I don't follow the intended logic of solving the sudoku, but it ends up in a repeated loop checking the same 2 cells over and over recursively until the stack is used up.  A way should be found to iterate with a for-loop rather than relying on recursion.

Comment: @stvcisco More likely it's a bug in the logic. Turning recursion into iteration would probably just reveal an infinite loop.

Comment: @all with a for-loop it workes fine so thank you all for your answers (Question closed).

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, "AWT-EventQueue-0" exceptions are from when you do something asynchronous with the HashMap. I would **highly** recommend that you separate the view from the model! And if necessary, separate the controller as well:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Do you get a number from what line the execution stoped? As this would really help identify from where the problem starts. Also you could do a debugging on the code. I recommend the Eclipse (Indigo), as it has a good debugger built in and a lot of other neat stuff. It grows on you!

---

*TIPS*

Try following the question form:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

because it's really hard when you leave 3 pages of code that's not relevant at all!
(About the language; the comment and variable names in germen, I think, is not so hard to understand. I mean, I know **what** you're instantiating so the names could be "asdf" or "foobar" for all I care.)

Also, please do put the constructor for the class as the first method after deceleration of class variables; as this makes it much easier to quickly identify it.

Comment: `AWT-EventQueue-0` is the name of the Event Dispatch Thread, and all traces involving the processing of GUI events, or runnables posted to the event queue, will show that. What does that have to do with "Doing something asynchronous with HashMap"? What does that even mean?

Comment: You're right.. My bad! I did a fast search and didn't read it properly.